# Django Map request body to Model

Tags: python, django

Hey guys is it possible to to see what a model/serialzer a request matches.

For instance if my body is sends:

```
  project_id: 1,
  title: "Hello",
  message: "World"
```

To run some code like

```
matchingModel = AllMyModels.map(request.body)
```

And have matchingModel be something like `Project`

Comment: What is your use case for this? why wouldn't you know what its trying to match? What if 2 serializers can both handle that payload?

Comment: I want to write middleware that changes the payload before it hits my view.  For example add more fields or remove some fields before the view takes over.

Comment: So I want to do some pre-proccessing before it hits my actual  endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

```
# mode creation
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'test'
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kwargs):
        clazz = cls(**kwargs)
        return clazz

    #create dictionary
    dic = {}
    dic['name'] = 'Test'

    # create object
    t = Test.create(**dic)
```